# Runtime error in following leetcode problem

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, sliding-window

Problem link - https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-average-subarray-i/

```
class Solution 
{
public:
double findMaxAverage(vector<int>& nums, int k)
{
deque<pair<int,int>> d;       //deque since its a sliding window problem
vector<double> ans;          //to return answer
double avg;
double sum=0;
int n=nums.size();

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(!d.empty() && d.front().second<=(i-k))                 //out of window size
            {
                avg=sum/k;
                ans.push_back(avg);          //push the average of k elements in answer vector
                sum=sum-d.front().first;     //remove the sum of first element when moving to next
                d.pop_front();               //remove front element of deque
                
            }
            
            d.push_back(make_pair(nums[i],i)); //push current element in deque
            sum=sum+d.back().first;            //add it to sum
            
        }
        
        return *max_element(ans.begin(), ans.end());   //return maximum average of subarray
    }
};
```

I was trying to solve leetcode problem 643 maximum average subarray I , which is an easy problem based on slididng window approach.

I wrote the code and got runtime error saying
"Line 811: Char 16: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'double' (stl_iterator.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c"

Can anyone please help with this ?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when the condition for `if(!d.empty() && d.front().second<=(i-k))` is *never* true ? What does `ans` end up holding (hint: *nothing*). So what do you suppose the dereference of `*max_element(ans.begin(), ans.end())` does when invoked on an empty sequence ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here

```
return *max_element(ans.begin(), ans.end());
```

If `ans` is empty, you dereference `ans.end()`.